# onListenerConnected from NotificationListenerService not called

Tags: java, android

I've looked at similar posts with the same question, yet none of the sugested fixes resolved such for me - I've attempted refactoring my service, I've checked the permissions in my xml, I've given the permission then restarted the device, and the service is definitely running - below is the service in full, and the manifest.

```
public class NotificationWatchdog extends NotificationListenerService {
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, NotificationListenerService.RankingMap rankingMap) {
    Log.i("NotifStatus", "Notification Recieved");
    Toast.makeText(this, sbn.getNotification().tickerText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn, rankingMap);
}
@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    Log.i("NotifStatus", "Listener Awake");
    super.onListenerConnected();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("ThreadStatus", "Thread Created.");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ThreadStatus", "Thread Awake");

   //WebRequest stuff here, not related to question.

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("ThreadStatus", "Thread Destroyed");
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProdigyEndpoint"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".NotificationWatchdog"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.notification.default_filter_types"
            android:value="1,2">
        </meta-data>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.notification.disabled_filter_types"
            android:value="2">
        </meta-data>
    </service>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Apologies in advance for what I'm sure will be a foolish question.

Comment: Don't override `onBind` - when you enable your notification service in settings system binds to it and you must allow `super.onBind` to return.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!